# Sorting array using ng-repeat, undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I am using an ng-repeat to loop through my data. However I use a bunch of filters to be applied. One of them is a filter to order the array I obtain. Usually I would to that using 'orderBy' as the default method in angular.

But I need to order my incoming array by price, and prices can be the same. In that case angular sometimes messes around with the minor issues.

Therefore, I wrote my own order filter:

```
app.filter('orderStructure',function(){
    return function(data){
      if(data) {
        data.sort(function(a,b) {
          if (a.price !== b.price) {
            return a.price - b.price
          }
          if(a.price === b.price){
            if (a.id < b.id) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.id > b.id) {
              return 1;
            }
          }
        });
      }return data;
    };
  })
```

This filters brings the data array in order and makes sure it's ordered by price and in case of two prices being the same it is ordered by ID (which is a string)
In the view I use.

```
<div ng-repeat="issue in data  |orderStructure | limitTo:itemsLimit()">
```

When I reload the site, I obtain the error that "undefined is not a function" indicating to the line of code  `data.sort(function(a,b) {`.

Is there anything wrong with my filter. I just dont seem to recognize my mistake here.

Hope you can help.

Note: Even if I order the data array beforehand by impelementing not a filter but a function to apply to data, I obtain the same error at data.sort()...
Is there any issue with that?

Comment: Could be that the `data` object isn't an array. The `sort` function is part of the array prototype.

Comment: data is an array of objects

Comment: You can orderby 2 attributes, you can orderby function. You do not need custom filter for this.

Comment: I see, but how can I make sure, that it prioritizes correctly. First sorting by price and and the by ID

Comment: I guess it just does so by default? http://jsfiddle.net/kFHXL/2/

Comment: @user3383709 angular's orderBy can do that for you, `orderBy: ['price', 'ID']`